# perl split the output after specific word occurrence and store them in hash or array

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, split

I have the below code and desired output is what I am looking for. I want to split the specific words in result which comes after "**transaction**","**user:**" and "**#**" and store them in 3 different arrays or hashes. Can anyone please help me to achieve it.

```
my @transaction_numbers = `cmd to get transaction numbers`;
chomp @transaction_numbers;

foreach my $number(@transaction_numbers) {
    my $result =`command to get result <transaction number> `;
    print $result;
}
```

Current output of `$result`:

```
transaction 1234567; promote; 2014/08/01 10:22:37 ; user: john
  # Performing a "promote" on file.
  /./abc/desf/test.pl 138699/1 (138700/1) 

transaction 4578643; promote; 2014/08/01 10:22:37 ; user: sam
  # Performing a "change" on file.
  /./abc/desf/test.pl 138699/1 (138700/1)
```

Desired output:

```
Number     User   Comments  
1234567    john   Performing a "promote" on file.  
4578643    sam    Performing a "change" on file.
```

Comment: Similar: [Reading output from command into Perl array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896246/reading-output-from-command-into-perl-array)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: it didnt help me, because I dont need all the details form `$result`. i am just looking for only 3 values..And not sure whether to take them into an array or hash? For transaction number and user , i can tae into 2 hashes as they have both key and value.But the comments have only value.

Comment: If you have all output in an array, you can loop through the array, pulling out the things you're interested in. Look at [regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) for extracting the info you want from each line. Note that [Jonathan Leffler's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10896432/176646) to the question I linked shows how to loop through an array obtained via backticks.

Comment: [Miller](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25086283/368630) gave you an answer to the question you posed. Please mark it as _the answer_. You can't keep adding on to it. Do you know Perl? If not get [Learning Perl](http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Perl-Randal-L-Schwartz/dp/1449303587/ref=sr_sp-atf_title_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1406921053&sr=8-1&keywords=learning+perl) and learn it. What you're asking is very basic. This site provides help for developers at all levels. It isn't suppose to be a for hire site.

Comment: @DavidW.: When you say its for all levels, I assume its for beginners as well. Dont assume that everybody will be at the same level as yours. Remember this before voting down someone's post. You didnt provide answer to my problem,but you can give so many free advices !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull your input into a string and then parse away:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $transaction_info = do {local $/; <DATA>};

# Header
printf "%-12s %-10s %s\n", qw(Number User Comments);

while ($transaction_info =~ /transaction (\d+).*user:\s*(\S+)\s*#\s*(.*)/g) {
    printf "%-12s %-10s %s\n", $1, $2, $3;
}

__DATA__
transaction 1234567; promote; 2014/08/01 10:22:37 ; user: john
  # Performing a "promote" on file.
  /./abc/desf/test.pl 138699/1 (138700/1) 

transaction 4578643; promote; 2014/08/01 10:22:37 ; user: sam
  # Performing a "change" on file.
  /./abc/desf/test.pl 138699/1 (138700/1)
```

Outputs:

```
Number       User       Comments
1234567      john       Performing a "promote" on file.
4578643      sam        Performing a "change" on file.
```

Comment: It worked. But In addition to this I need one more functionality.  For example , if the user enters number `1234567` I need to display its respective user and comments. In this case `john` and `Performing a "promote" on file.`. For that do I need to store them in hash with `number` as key and `user`,`comments` as its value? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes, a hash of array refs would work just fine for that.

Comment: Can you plz edit your above code with an example of how can I do that? I mean how to associate 2 values for a key ? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Sorry, as [David W](http://stackoverflow.com/users/368630/david-w) pointed out in a comment above, that is one level of hand-holding too far.  Trying reading [`perldsc` - Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) or [Modern Perl Book](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2014/).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:

```
    my %data = ();
    foreach my $number(@transaction_numbers) {
        my $result =`command to get result <transaction number> `;
        print $result;

        my @lines = split "\n" , $result;
        $lines[0] =~ /transaction\s+(\d+).+user:\s(.+)/;
        $data{$1}{'user'} = $2;
        $data{$1}{'comment'} = $lines[1]; 
    }
```